# In Oracle database unable to create new user

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle21c

when i try to create new user in oracle database it showing error as username and password wrong.

Tried with multiple time with restarting also, still same issue.

I want to create a new user in the Oracle database. Username and password is correct.

Comment: There's no any line of code in your question, the only way to answer it is to guess. Please edit it and provide an error message you have

Comment: While trying to create a new user in the Oracle database, it shows an error as test failed ORA-01017: invalid username/password logon denied

Comment: If Oracle says that username and/or password are incorrect, I'd rather believe it than you because that's pretty much *basic* feature since the first Oracle database version. I sincerely doubt that there's a bug in that. Therefore: **a)** make up your mind: are you using Oracle 11g or 21c (as you used both tags) **b)** post EVERYTHING you did, step-by-step. It would be good if you used SQL Plus, a command-line tool, so that we'd exactly see what you did and how Oracle responded. Because, description you posted so far doesn't help much.

Comment: Please show your exact code. It's clear you are not creating a user but trying to log in. But we have to see your code to let you know what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You must connect to the PDB not the CDB:

```
alter session set container = nameofpdb;
```

after connecting.